# My code takes a blank cell and adjusts it to say "Empty", what is the most efficient way to turn the text red?

Tags: excel, vba

My entire code is rather large, and goes through a large amount of data.  In order to save time I need to be as efficient as possible.  For the following code, how do I turn the color of text red without a new line/if statement?

I know I can do another if statement, but this takes precious time and I am afraid of running into errors 20 minutes into running my code.

```
For Each r In Intersect(newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ:AQ"),   newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
If IsEmpty(r.Value2) Or Trim(r.Value2) = "" Then
  'below is the line/cell I need to make red
 r.Value2 = "Empty"
```

Comment: Just use Conditional Formatting for the Range. Pick Rule Type *Format only cells that contain*, then Format only cells with *Blanks*

Answer (score 1):

To improve the efficiency of your procedure, add these lines at the beginning of it:

```
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
```

and these at the end of it:

```
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
```

Also instead of working the range cell by cell suggest using a method that sets a `range` that includes all the required `cells` and update the `value` and the `font.color` all at once.

Depending on what you would like to achieve use one of these methods:

1. To get all the *"empty"* `Cells` excluding those containing formulas that return `""` or cells with a value equal to `""`; use the [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells). This method is applied by the function `SpecialCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty`
2. To get all the *"empty"* `Cells` including those with a value equal to `""` and excluding those containing formulas that return `""`; use the [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) with `LookIn:=xlFormulas`. This method is applied by the function `FindCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty`
3. To get all the *"empty"* `Cells` including those with a value equal to `""` and those containing formulas that return `""`; use the [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) with `LookIn:=xlValues`. This method is applied by the function `FindCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty`

Use the procedure `Cells_MarkAs_Empty` to call the required method. The procedure should be called as:

```
Call Cells_MarkAs_Empty(bMethod)
```

where `bMethod` is a whole number from 1 to 3 indicating the method to apply
  1. SpecialCells
  2. Find (LookIn:=xlFormulas)
  3. Find (LookIn:=xlValues)

```
Sub Cells_MarkAs_Empty(bMethod As Byte)
Rem bMethod: whole number from 1 to 3
Rem Method 1: SpecialCells
Rem Method 2: Find (LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Rem Method 3: Find (LookIn:=xlValues)
Dim rSrc As Range, rTrg As Range

    Rem Validate Input
    If bMethod < 1 Or bMethod > 3 Then
        MsgBox "Method: " & bMethod & " is invalid!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Rem Set Source Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
        Set rSrc = Intersect(.Range("J:J"), .UsedRange)
    End With

    Select Case bMethod
    Case 1:     Set rTrg = SpecialCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty(rSrc)
    Case 2:     Set rTrg = FindCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty(rSrc, xlFormulas)
    Case 3:     Set rTrg = FindCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty(rSrc, xlValues)
    End Select

    Rem Mark Target Range
    If Not (rTrg Is Nothing) Then
        With rTrg
            .Value2 = "Empty"
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With: End If

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    End Sub
```

.

```
Function SpecialCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty(rSrc As Range) As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SpecialCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty = rSrc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
```

.

```
Function FindCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty(rSrc As Range, vLookIn As Variant) As Range
Const kWhat As String = ""
Dim rFnd As Range, rCll As Range, s1st As String

    With rSrc

        Set rCll = .Find(What:=kWhat, _
            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=vLookIn, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not (rCll Is Nothing) Then

            s1st = rCll.Address
            Set rFnd = rCll

            Do
                Set rCll = .FindNext(After:=rCll)
                If rCll.Address = s1st Then Exit Do
                Set rFnd = Union(rFnd, rCll)
            Loop Until rCll.Address = s1st

    End If: End With

    Rem Set Results
    Set FindCells_ƒMarkAs_Empty = rFnd

    End Function
```

Check the following pages for details about the resources used:
[With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)
[Application.EnableEvents property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents)
[Application.DisplayAlerts property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts)
[Application.ScreenUpdating property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating)
[Application.Calculation property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculation)

Comment: Thank you for your help! With what you said to put before and after the procedure... is that only in this sub, or in my main sub where I call the rest of the subs?

Comment: That goes in the main sub. However, care must be taken when any procedure uses the result of a formula, then you have to ensure the values taken are updated. There is plenty of information on this subject in the web try: [excel vba how to use application.calculation](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+how+to+use+application.calculation)

Comment: @EEM FYI `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` does not capture some cells that `Trim(r.Value2) = ""` would, eg formulas that are returning an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen will update the code in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I added the line of code to turn that text red.
Since you mentioned that you want your code to run as quickly as possible I hope that you are familiar with `Application.Calculation = xlManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` etc. etc.

Another thing you could do is storing your worksheet into an array and operate inside of memory instead of operating directly on the sheet.

```
For Each r In Intersect(newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ:AQ"), _ 
              newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)

    If IsEmpty(r.Value2) Or Trim(r.Value2) = "" Then
        r.Value2 = "Empty"
        'The line below will change the font color to red
        r.Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Comment: What kind of issues can I expect if I use the two you mentioned up top?  My apologies, I have been learning as I create this and those are new to me

Comment: You won't expect any issues. You disable `ScreenUpdating` before the main code and enable it right back after the main code. The only thing is that you won't see how your macro changes the sheet, but that's exactly the point...this is why it would run faster.